# React docker container: Module parse failed: Unexpected token

Tags: reactjs, docker

I am trying to move a react project to a docker container but it fails everytime no matter what I try. When I run the same commands in my terminal everything is fine so I kinda dont know what to do anymore. When researching this problem people have changed things in their webpack.config but doing their solutions doesnt work for me. I also have seen people adding a lot of their files so if anyone needs more specific files please let me know. Here are the three which seemingly cause the problem (I think)

Error in the terminal:

```
=> ERROR [build 8/8] RUN yarn run build                                                                                                                                                           2.5s 
------
 > [build 8/8] RUN yarn run build:
0.858 yarn run v1.22.19
0.924 $ webpack --mode production
2.405 assets by status 3.62 KiB [cached] 2 assets
2.405 runtime modules 8.01 KiB 10 modules
2.405 cacheable modules 257 bytes
2.405   ./src/index.js 24 bytes [built] [code generated]
2.405   ./src/bootstrap.js 233 bytes [built] [code generated] [1 error]
2.405
2.405 ERROR in ./src/bootstrap.js 7:12
2.405 Module parse failed: Unexpected token (7:12)
2.405 You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
2.405 |
2.405 | const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
2.405 > root.render(<App />);
2.405 |
2.405  @ ./src/index.js 1:0-21
2.405
2.405 webpack 5.88.2 compiled with 1 error in 615 ms
2.449 info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
2.449 error Command failed with exit code 1.
------
Dockerfile:9
--------------------
   7 |     RUN npm install react-scripts@5.0.1 -g --silent
   8 |     COPY . ./
   9 | >>> RUN yarn run build
  10 |
  11 |     FROM nginx:stable
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c yarn run build" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:lts as build
WORKDIR /app
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
RUN yarn install
RUN npm install react-scripts@5.0.1 -g --silent
COPY . ./
RUN yarn run build

FROM nginx:stable
COPY --from=build /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx","-g","daemon off;"]
```

Webpack.config.js:

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require("webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin");
const deps = require("./package.json").dependencies;
module.exports = {
    mode: "development",
    devServer: {
        port: 8082,
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".jsx", ".js", ".json"],
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.m?js$/,
                enforce: "pre",
                use: ["source-map-loader"],
            },
            {
                test: /\.png$/,
                type: "asset/resource",
            },
            {
                test: /\.m?js/,
                type: "javascript/auto",
                resolve: {
                    fullySpecified: false,
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.(css|s[ac]ss)$/i,
                use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "postcss-loader"],
            },
            {
                test: /\.jsx/,
                loader: "babel-loader",
            },
            {
                test: /\.(ts|tsx|js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                },
            },
            {
                test: /.json$/i,
                type: "json",
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new ModuleFederationPlugin({
            name: "Test01",
            filename: "remoteEntry.js",
            remotes: {
                Test02: "Test02@http://localhost:8083/remoteEntry.js",
            },
            shared: {
                ...deps,
                react: {
                    singleton: true,
                    requiredVersion: deps.react,
                },
                "react-dom": {
                    singleton: true,
                    requiredVersion: deps["react-dom"],
                },
            },
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: "./public/index.html",
        }),
    ],
};
```

bootstrap.js:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";
import "semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<App />);
```

Doing everything in order of the Dockerfile on my own PC builds the project as intended but for some reason it doesnt on the docker container.